# Request spec with devise_token_auth + omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently writing an API with Rails 5 using `devise_token_auth` and `omniauth` as authentication strategy.

To check if the omniauth authentication works, I wrote a request spec:

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(
  {
      provider: 'facebook',
      uid: '123456'
  })
Rails.application.env_config["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"]  = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
get '/omniauth/facebook/callback'
expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
```

When I run the test I have to following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/gaetan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.39/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:14:in `redirect_callbacks'
```

Here is the line 14:

```
devise_mapping = [request.env['omniauth.params']['namespace_name'],
```

So I guess that's because `omniauth.params` is `nil`. Does it mean that I also have to mock the params? How?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this problem? I'm still having this issue. I've tested `Rails.application.env_config['omniauth.params'] = { key: 'value' }` but it returns an empty hash in the controller.

Comment: Nope I didn't...

Answer (score 0):

### Controller

(ex: Users::OmniauthCallbacksController)

```
def omniauth_params
  request.env['omniauth.params']
end
```

### Spec

```
allow_any_instance_of(Users::OmniauthCallbacksController).to(receive(:omniauth_params).and_return('namespace_name' => 'namespace_name'))
```

or

```
allow_any_instance_of(Users::OmniauthCallbacksController).to(receive(:omniauth_params).and_return(OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({:namespace_name => 'namespace_name'})))
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Could you be a bit more descriptive? Why the OP should use those methods? What is the difference between the first one and the second one? :)